# How do I get the full uri of a selected entry from EE's Relationships field?

Tags: relationships, page-uri

I'm trying to use EE's Relationships field to select a page and get the full URI of that page.

Basically I want to be able to allow the client to select an entry from several different channels, and link directly to that entry.  Maybe noteworthy - this site does not use structure or the pages module.

Here is the code I'm trying to use, where `link_sbb` is my Relationships field name:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="sidebar_banner" limit="1" dynamic="off"}
   <a href="{link_sbb}{link_sbb:page_uri}{/link_sbb}">Learn More<span class="arrow"></span></a>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I can get `url_title` to work but I don't want to use `path=""` as the path's can be different, they can select pages from different channels/sections of the site etc.  The `permalink` and `page_url` variables don't return a value either.

Is there an easy way to achieve this with EE's Relationships field?

***EDIT:***

Examples of possible URL's

1. /products/category
2. /products/category/subcategory
3. /products/category/{url_title}
4. /products/category/subcategory/{url_title}
5. /applications/category
6. /applications/category/{url_title}
7. /resources/category
8. /company/category
9. /news/category
10. /news/{url_title}
11. /single-page

Comment: What kind of url structure are you looking to get for your link when it's output? Can you give an example?

Comment: The url structure may be `/segment_1/segment_2/segment_3/url_title` or `/segment_1/segment_2/url_title` or `/segment_1/category/url_title` - they will vary from url's with categories, # of segments, etc.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that **entries don't have URIs in EE**. Content is completely separated from URL routing - it will appear wherever you decide to call it in your templates (which are [essentially analogous to routing in EE](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/url_structure.html)). (The exception is when you set a [Pages URI](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/pages/index.html#introduction), or use an add-on like [Structure](http://buildwithstructure.com) which subverts this fundamental tenet of EE.)

So, as [Siebird pointed out](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/16699/how-do-i-get-the-full-uri-of-a-selected-entry-from-ees-relationships-field#comment19204_16700), you have to decide where each related entry should link based on whatever data you have at your disposal (channel, entry_id, segment variables, etc), and then construct each link directly in your template code.

Answer (score 3):

In order for `page_uri` variable to work, either the pages or structure modules need to be installed. More [here](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#page-uri)

Re: other options, I would either install one of the modules or you will have to have several conditions within the `link_sbb` tag pair to determine the correct path.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I installed the pages module, but the above code still doesn't return a value.  I also tested on a site with Structure installed, same result :/

Comment: Did you go into each entry and update the `page_uri` field under the 'Pages' tab?

Comment: No I didn't but I see now what you mean, I'm hoping there is an easier solution, this site has 100's of entries/pages - having to go into each individual entry and manually input the full URI won't be fun...

Comment: What are all the possibilities of URL's? A conditional might be the easier route since you have 100's of entries. Update your question

Comment: I added the possible URL's to my question - Based on what you've said and [a similar question I found](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/14838/relationship-tag-link-to-different-channels) - I'll try setting up a conditional with switchee...